# is there any associated cost to attaching firebase realtime database listeners other than the data dowloaded?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any cost associated with attaching realtime database listeners ex child_added, child_changed etc. other than the download/read operation?

lets say i have a list of 100 messages in the DB. Users are allowed to like/edit their message.

Is there a cost difference if i attach 100 child_changed listeners (per message listener) vs 1 listener for the whole list ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) plans, you will not be charged for using multiple listeners.
However, more listeners can lead to more read/write operations, so that might cause you to be charged higher than expected.